# Can you tell UIWebView to use a white indicator style?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm running into a case where I have in-application HTML documentation that uses a dark background, but the default scroll indicator for UIWebView is getting lost in that background.  The following is an example of this:

[image: Image of UIWebView dark scroller]
<sub>(source: [sunsetlakesoftware.com](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/so-webview.jpg))</sub>

With UIScrollView, which UIWebView resembles in its behavior, you can set the indicatorStyle property to UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite, which results in the desired behavior:

[image]
<sub>(source: [sunsetlakesoftware.com](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/so-scrollview.jpg))</sub>

I can't seem to find a similar property in the exposed interface for UIWebView.  Is there a CSS trick or other way to force the scroll indicator to a lighter style?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Starting iOS 5.0 onwards, one can now customize the scrolling behavior of the web view by accessing the 'scrollview' property to achieve the desired functionality:

```
webView.scrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
```

Answer (score 6):

If you do want to scan the subviews and attempt to gracefully fail if something changes in the future this currently works:

```
    //set a white scroll bar
    for (UIView *subview in [webView subviews]) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UIScroller")] || [subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UIScrollView")]) {
            if ([subview respondsToSelector:@selector(setIndicatorStyle:)]) {
                [(UIScrollView *)subview setIndicatorStyle:UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite];
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

Though things *could* still break in the future if setIndicatorStyle: changes to expect a non-enumerated value... but I doubt that would happen.

Answer (score 1):

Scan the subviews and test for a UIScrollView.  You can then programatically set the indicator.

Comment: Unfortunately, UIWebView uses a UIScroller to handle its internal scrolling (seen by traversing the internal view hierarchy).  This is a privately defined class, so it's a really bad idea to touch it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no public API for this in the 2.x SDK. File a bug/case/radar asking for it in 3.0.

Comment: I was afraid as much, but I'd hoped that someone had a trick that I'd missed.  I'll file a feature enhancement request.